# Why is Deleting a Heap Allocated Byte Array Causing a Heap Corruption

Tags: c++, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I am trying to create something like the stack but it is heap allocated. However, when the program tries to exit, it says that there is a heap corruption detected. I am using visual studio 2019.

Here is a file with a class called vstack that uses a heap allocated byte array:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>

typedef unsigned char BYTE;
typedef BYTE* STACK;

struct VARIABLE {
    std::string name;
    int location = 0;
    char type = 0;
};


class Vstack {
    STACK vstack = nullptr;
    int stack_top = 0, capacity = 0;
    std::vector<VARIABLE> variables;

    //resizes the byte array
    void ReAlloc(size_t NewSize) {
        STACK NewData = new BYTE[NewSize];

        for (int i = 0; i != stack_top; i++)
            NewData[i] = vstack[i];

        delete[] vstack;
        vstack = NewData;
        capacity = NewSize;
    }

public:

    Vstack() {
        ReAlloc(2);
    }

    //create a long long int stored on the vstack
    void Create(std::string name, long long int value) {
        if (stack_top + sizeof(long long int) >= capacity)
            ReAlloc(capacity * 2);

        VARIABLE var;
        var.name = name;
        var.location = stack_top;
        variables.push_back(var);
        *(long long int*)(vstack + stack_top) = value;
        stack_top += sizeof(long long int);
    }


    //gets a pointer to a variable with the given name
    void* Read(std::string name) {
        for (int i = 0; i != variables.size(); i++)
            if (variables[i].name == name)
                return (vstack + variables[i].location);
        return nullptr;
    }

    ~Vstack() {
        delete[] vstack;
    }
};
```

Here is the main file:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"Vstack.h"

int main() {
    Vstack stack;
    stack.Create("x", 15);
    std::cout << *(long long int*)stack.Read("x") << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It isn't causing it, it is detecting it. You corrupted it somewhere else, probably by under-running or over-running the array bounds.

Comment: A debugger, and/or an static memory analyzer should find the memory corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> int main() {
>   Vstack stack;
> ```

At this point, `stack.capacity` is 2, from the default constructor.

> ```
>   stack.Create("x", 15);
> ```

At this point, `stack.capacity` has doubled to 4, and you just wrote a `long long`, which is guaranteed to be at least **8** bytes. Hence, you just overwrote the end of your buffer.

Perhaps instead of `if` you need more capacity, you should check `while` you need more capacity. Or you could choose an operation that guarantees sufficient capacity (doubling the capacity does not, but doubling then adding `sizeof(long long int)` would).

One way you can more easily detect something like this is with an `assert`. You could, after increasing `stack_top` at the end of `Create()`, `assert(stack_top <= capacity)`.